# Stat draining monsters like a shadow?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I was wondering if there are more stat draining monsters like the shadow and the vargouille in Volo's

Comment: What's keeping you from checking these yourself?

Comment: I don't own all the books and have not read every stat block of the ones I do. So I figured that people who have might be willing to help out.

Comment: It might be better to ask "how do I find all the stat draining monsters like Shadow?"

Comment: Do you want a complete list of all stat-draining monsters from all ever published source books? From any particular source book? Or do you just wonder if such monsters exist? (the question body in its current state implies the latter)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to find this? What problem would having this list fill or solve?

Comment: Not to be rude, but it would also be helpful if you could rephrase your body & title to form coherent sentences, and not look like a list of keywords. It's just a really convenient way to make the question more appealing, as (at least my) motivation for investing effort into an answer tends to be higher if the asker appears to have put some effort into the question as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Shadow (Shadowy Duplicate, Shadow Assassin, Reflections)

The Shadow, Shadowy Duplicate, and Shadowy Assassin have the Strength Drain Ability:

> **Strength Drain.** *Melee Weapon Attack*: +4 to hit, reach 5 ft., one creature. *Hit*: 9 (2d6 + 2) necrotic damage, and the target's Strength score is reduced by 1d4. The target dies if this reduces its Strength to 0. Otherwise, the reduction lasts until the target finishes a short or long rest.

Reflections are creatures similar to Shadows introduced in *Tasha's Cauldron* as part of the Mirror Zone environmental hazard:

> Reflections of 1d4 creatures in the region emerge from mirrors and attack. The reflections are two-dimensional, shimmering versions of the creatures that cast them. Treat the reflections as shadows that are fey instead of undead and vulnerable to bludgeoning damage instead of radiant.

#### Intellect Devourer

The Intellect Devourer's Devour Intellect ability says:

> **Devour Intellect.** The intellect devourer targets one creature it can see within 10 feet of it that has a brain. The target must succeed on a DC 12 Intelligence saving throw against this magic or take 11 (2d10) psychic damage. Also on a failure, roll 3d6: If the total equals or exceeds the target’s Intelligence score, that score is reduced to 0. The target is stunned until it regains at least one point of Intelligence.

#### Maurezhi

The Maurezhi's Bite says:

> **Bite.** *Melee Weapon Attack*: +6 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. *Hit*: 14 (2d10 + 3) piercing damage. If the target is a humanoid, its Charisma score is reduced by 1d4. This reduction lasts until the target finishes a short or long rest. The target dies if this reduces its Charisma to 0. It rises 24 hours later as a ghoul, unless it has been revived or its corpse has been destroyed.

#### Phylaskia

The Phylaskia from *Mythic Odysseys of Theros* has Strength Drain:

> **Strength Drain**. *Melee Weapon Attack*: +9 to hit, reach 5 ft., one creature. *Hit*: 12 (2d6 + 5) necrotic damage. Unless the target is immune to necrotic damage, its Strength score is reduced by 1d4. The target dies if this reduces its Strength to 0. Otherwise, the reduction lasts until the target finishes a short or long rest.

#### Dyrrn (Lair Action)

One of Dyrrn's lair actions says:

> Each creature of Dyrrn’s choice that it can see within 120 feet of it must succeed on a DC 23 Wisdom saving throw or take 26 (4d12) psychic damage. Unless the target has immunity to psychic damage, its Intelligence score is reduced by 1d4 each time it fails the saving throw for this lair action. The target dies if its Intelligence score is reduced to 0. The reduction lasts until the target finishes a short or long rest.

#### Vargouille

The Vargouille's Kiss says:

> **Kiss**. The vargouille kisses one incapacitated humanoid within 5 feet of it. The target must succeed on a DC 12 Charisma saving throw or become cursed. The cursed target loses 1 point of Charisma after each hour, as its head takes on fiendish aspects. The curse doesn’t advance while the target is in sunlight or the area of a daylight spell; don’t count that time. When the cursed target’s Charisma becomes 2, it dies, and its head tears from its body and becomes a new vargouille. Casting remove curse, greater restoration, or a similar spell on the target before the transformation is complete can end the curse. Doing so undoes the changes made to the target by the curse.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is quite a list. I find it interesting that there are no WIS, CON, DEX draining creatures.